# Is there a name for arrangements of n sets consisting of unique single values for the intersection of each k of them?

Tags: combinatorics, terminology, combinatorial-designs

For example the sets {1,2},{1,3} and {2,3} are such that each 2 of them intersect in unique values.  This can be done for any n and k where n is the number of sets and k is the number of intersections.  All you have to do assign one of C(n, k) values to each set indexed by a combination of k of n.  In the above example, C(n, k) = 3. Assign 1 to sets 1 and 2, 2 to sets 2 and 3, and 3 to sets 1 and 3.

The total number of entries is kC(n, k) and the size of each set is C(n-1, k-1). I can't think of any applications for this, but there is a nice symmetry, so I thought that maybe someone might have thought it was deserving of a name, and maybe found something interesting to say about it.

Comment: This relates to something called affine spaces, and is the basis for the card game Dobble (aka Spot It!) as discussed in [this Stand-up Maths video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VTDKqW_GLkw).

Comment: I'm confused, are you also requiring each set to have exactly $k$ elements? That is, would the [Fano plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fano_plane) $\{1,2,3\},\{1,4,5\},\{1,6,7\},\{2,4,6\},\{2,5,7\},\{3,5,6\},\{3,4,7\}$ be a valid example for $n=7,k=2$? It seems like you are, otherwise why bring up $\binom nk$, but you did not state that as a rule. I think this post could benefit by very clearly out all of the defining features you want this system of sets to have.

Comment: Sorry for any confusion. k is the number of intersections, each of which contains a single element. Each set has C(n-1,k-1) elements.

Comment: Ignore the above comment.  What I should have said was:
Sorry for any confusion. k is the number of  sets in each intersection, each of which contains a single element. There are C(n, k)  such intersections. Each set has C(n-1, k-1) elements.

Comment: This may help clarify things.  For n=5 and k=3, a group of sets satisfying the conditions is {1,2,3,4,5,6}, {1,2,3,7,8,9}, {1,4,5,7,8,10}, {2,4,6,7,9,10},  and {3,5,6,8,9,10}  Every value is in 3 of the sets and every 3 sets intersect in exactly one value.

Answer (score 1):

This actually belongs to two areas:

[**Finite Geometry**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_geometry).  In this world we have *points* (the elements $1,2,\ldots$ in your example) and *lines* which are sets of points ($\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\{2,3\}$ in your example).  Most often we are interested in *incidence geometries* in which (a) every point lies on the same number of lines, (b) every line has the same number of points, and (c) the lines have some interesting intersection property.

[**Design Theory**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Theory).  In this world, we have *points* which are elements, and *blocks* which are sets of points.  Most often we are interested in *block designs* in which every (a) every point belongs to the same number of points, (b) every block contains the same number of points, and (c) and two points determine a unique block.

Now, the particular case where we have the points $1,2,3$ and the lines/blocks $\{1,2\}$, $\{2,3\}$, $\{1,3\}$ with unique intersections, is not going to generalize as easily as suggested in the question.  The reason is that when $k \geq 2$, we have $\binom{n}{\text{k}}$ blocks of size $k$ which is usually greater than $n$, but there are only $n$ intersections possible (since they are unique).

> In the above example, C(n, k) = 3. Assign 1 to sets 1 and 2, 2 to sets 2 and 3, and 3 to sets 1 and 3.

If we use this method, when $n=4$, we get the sets $\{1,2,3\},\{1,2,4\},\{1,3,4\},\{2,3,4\}$, and any two of these sets have a size-$2$ intersection.  If our lines/blocks are pairs of the size-$(n-1)$ subsets of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ which intersect at $n-2$ points, then we get the [complete graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_graph).

Since the properties you're interested in are (a) subsets of a given size and (b) two subsets intersect at some fixed number of points, your example has the interesting generalization to the [Johnson Graph](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/JohnsonGraph.html) $J(n,2)$:

> The Johnson graph $J(n,k)$ has vertices given by the $k$-subsets of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$, with two vertices connected iff their intersection has size $k-1$.

And the given example is $J(3,2)$.